# Why function declaration is crashing my react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to calculate the total of my courses. I am passing a function declaration to the course but it is crashing my app. I am trying to setSum inside an **addExercises** function.

I have a component named Content:

```
function Content({ parts }) {

    const [sum, setSum] = useState(0)

    return (
        <div>
            {parts.map(part => (
                <Part name={part.name} 
                        exercise={part.exercises} 
                        key={part.id}
                        addExercises={() => setSum(sum + part.exercises)} />   
            ))}
            Total Exercises: {sum}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Then I have a component Part: -

```
function Part({name, exercise, addExercises}) {
    addExercises();
    return (
        <div>
            <p>{name} {exercise}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I am passing this data to content as props: -

```
parts: [
      {
        name: 'Fundamentals of React',
        exercises: 10,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'Using props to pass data',
        exercises: 7,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'State of a component',
        exercises: 14,
        id: 3
      }
```

Comment: What **exactly** does "crashing my app" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: you can't alter state as part of rendering, which is what you're doing here by calling `addExercises()` in the body of your function component. This will cause an infinite loop. Put it in a `useEffect` instead, if you really want to update it in every render (although this seems unlikely to be what you actually want).

Answer (score 2):

1. You call `addExercises` every time the component renders.
2. This changes the value of `sum` which triggers a rerender.
3. GOTO 1

You have an infinite loop.

Maybe you want your function call inside `useEffect` hook.

Maybe you shouldn't pass it down to the component at all, but put a `useMemo` hook in the parent component which generates the `sum` by looping over the array separately.

```
function Content({ parts }) {

    const sum = useMemo(() => {
        return parts.reduce(
            (total, part) => {
                return total + part.exercises;
            },
            0
        );
    }, [parts]);
```